# Is it possible to update reference files (images, documents) in a built MSI without rebuilding it?

Tags: .net, deployment, windows-installer

In a situation where you have a built MSI for a .net desktop application which includes lots of 'static content' in the form of documents and images, is it possible to update the static content without rebuilding the installer?

I've found a tool that enables poking inside an installer - but it seems ot be read-only

http://lessmsi.activescott.com/

Given that we have access to the source code of the project - is it possible to set up an installer with an external referenced folder of some kind that would enable this more easily?

Ideally I'd like to have a single file that a user could download which includes the core code build and the current reference files - but because the files change often I don't want to be tied into creating a new build each time they change.

I'm not keen on maintaining an update web service for the client application to update the references from the server (although that is another option if editing MSI files is too complicated).

Any thoughts or best practices for this scenario appreciated,

Cheers,

-Kaine-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible by using `Orca` or similar tools. [Orca.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370557%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is a database table editor for creating and editing Windows Installer packages and merge modules.
[Here](http://www.instedit.com/) is another tool.

Answer (score 0):

In theory you could do this with Orca, but in practice there are so many things that can go wrong it may not be worth it. Just as a couple of examples. If you change a versioned file you'd need to remember to go and change the Version in the File table, and also the size if you care that it's all computed correctly, and if it's managed code then go into the MsiAssemblyName table to make those values correct. If you change a data file then you'd need to go into the MsiFileHash table to add the actual file hash of the new files. If you are sure that you or someone else can correctly modify all the required MSI content when files are substituted then good luck with that - in reality you'll be doing a hand build of the MSI by manually changing its content and fiddling around in all the places in the MSI file that need changing when files change. Why bother? You may be thinking that Windows Installer is just a dumb file copier that doesn't care about file content, but that's incorrect.